# The use of "NP + for someone doing sth"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, infinitive-vs-gerund, construction

> Peter Quill: She betrayed Ronan. He's coming back for her. And when he does, that's
>   when you... ( Quill makes a gesture of slicing his own throat )
>
> Drax: Why would I put my finger on his throat? ( Drax is completely literal. Metaphors are gonna go over his head. )
>
> Peter Quill: What? ... No, it's a symbol. This is **a symbol for you slicing his throat**.
>
> Drax: I would not slice his throat. I would cut his head clean off.
>
> Peter Quill: It's **a general expression for you killing somebody**. You've heard of this. You've seen this, right?
>
> – *Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014)

These bolded expressions don't often appear in daily conversation. Do they sound formal?

I would use "a symbol **of you slicing his throat**", "a general expression **of you killing somebody**" or "a symbol **for you to slice his throat**", "a general expression **for you to kill somebody**" instead.

Would my suggested replacement bring any difference in meaning or emphasis? Is **you** non-obligatory in the original examples?

Answer (score 1):

" <kbd>⌘</kbd>   is the symbol for the Command key on a Mac."

Swapping that to 'of' wouldn't work in that case.

Sticking with computer comparisons, "A keyboard is the <strike>general expression</strike> term for the device used to enter letters & numbers..."

Compared to, for instance, "the [country of your choice] flag is a symbol of democracy"

That would imply that 'of' could be used where the symbol is not identifiably solely used for that purpose. In the above example, there could be many other symbols of democracy & the main purpose of the flag is not to signify democracy.

The 'finger across throat' gesture really only has one meaning [aside from the joke generated by Drax]

*Edit:* It does have a secondary meaning, but I think that is derived from the first; that of 'cut' [film industry, stop filming, rather than scissors & paper] or 'stop'

Comment: Is the **for** the same as that in "V **for** Vendetta"?

Comment: grammatically, I'm not certain [not really my strong point] but that would be common parlance, like "A for Apple, B for Ball… etc sometimes cast as "A *is* for Apple...

Comment: For means more like "in exchange for", though that's not it exactly. It indicates an equivalence, *can replace*.

Comment: My favorite reference just says *We use -ing forms after certain verb + object combinations. "Do you mind me smoking?" Not a lot of help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Does the construction sound formal?

No, it's actually an informal way to offer a definition of some term.

Comment: You are always economical with your words. :)

Comment: I will take that as a compliment :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer directly and certainly, but some of my thoughts might be relevant, and perhaps stimulate something more definative.

We often use *for* to introduce the subject of an infinitive [for + subject + to (verb)]: *This is for him to use.* That is likely the pattern you are inclined to notice and follow.

Many grammars have chapters or pages on choosing between infinitives and -ing forms. The rules usually specify which form follows (or can/can't follow) particular verbs,  But I think we usually (always?) see examples and simplifications of incredibly numerous, complex, and subtle combinations of factors that actually shape our decisions.

There is a commonly cited guideline that *we use -ing forms for activities.* This lets us use actions more like nouns. We say, for example, *Do you mind me smoking?

We can sometimes see the verb *mind* listed with a rule/guideline that *We use -ing forms after certain verb + object combinations.* But we won't find *is/be* listed as one such, so this kind of guidance is of limited value.

An intuitive way for me to see this is that the activity of slicing is the "most important" concept in the phrase *for you slicing _____.* If we think of *you slicing his throat* as a clause, *slicing* is more centrally the topic ("subject"?) of the clause than is *you.* We could say *expression for *one* slicing" with relatively little change in meaning.

So, I speculate that the -ing form is used because the form is more "subject-like" or "noun-like" than is *to slice.*